# How to take field inputs for curl from a text file?

Tags: curl

I need to make POST requests to a website with form like loginId="somestr".
Normal curl command looks like this:
curl -d loginId="abc" http://abasdas.com/efg.
How can I automate multiple requests by giving the values of loginId from a text file?

Answer (score 1):

This is more a job for your shell/programming language. For example, bash would be:

```
for id in abc def ghi; do
    curl -d loginId="$id" http://...
done
```